# Use html5 validations even if form is never being submitted?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I am doing is catching the click action on my form's submit button, `preventDefault()`ing it, doing some computation, and then making an ajax call instead of submitting the form.

Is there a way to use javascript to force the html5 validators to fire even if the form isn't being submitted?

```
 $('#submitButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault(); //stop the form from submitting

        //Do computation

        $.post('/comments', values, function(results) {
            hideForm($('#new_comment_' + parentId));
            parent.children('.children').prepend(results);
        }, 'html');
    });
```

Comment: Yes I can roll my own validation in javascript, but html5's required="required" tag is nice and simple and sets up a decently looking popup GUI for you. Less work and less code complexity is always a plus, but it ends up taking too much work to use html5's validations I can just make my own javascript ones.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It works just fine, I tested in latest Chrome and Firefox. Just `e.preventDefault()` on the `<form>`:

**html:**

```
<form method="post" action="test.html">
    <input type="text" required></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**jQ:**

```
$('form').submit(function(e){ e.preventDefault(); });
```

**example:** http://jsfiddle.net/elclanrs/2nnLc/2/

Comment: Ah, catch the form submission instead of the submit button click. Much smarter idea thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Using html5 constraints the form object has some new methods. For example you can call checkValidity() on the form object to check the input.

```
<form method="post" action="test.html" id="myForm">
    <input type="text" required></input>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submitButton">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#submitButton').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        alert($("#myForm").get()[0].checkValidity());
    })
</script>
```